# Splitting URLs into hierarchy-level directories

Tags: python, strings, python-2.x, combinatorics, url

The goal is to split a URL like `http://q.com/a/b/c` to:

```
['http://q.com/a', 'http://q.com/a/b', 'http://q.com/a/b/c']
```

My code:

```
import urlparse


def get_domain_with_protocol(url):
    url_parts = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    return "{scheme}://{netloc}/".format(
        scheme=url_parts.scheme, 
        netloc=url_parts.netloc
    )


def get_url_directories_combinations(url):
    url = url.rstrip('/')
    path = urlparse.urlparse(url).path[1:]
    parts = path.split('/')
    domain_with_protocol = get_domain_with_protocol(url)

    url_combinations = [domain_with_protocol + '/'.join(parts[:index + 1])
                        for index in range(len(parts))]
    return url_combinations


print get_url_directories_combinations('http://example.com/a/b/c/')
```

I think this code is ugly and a more Pythonic approach might be possible. There are libraries like [`hyperlink`](https://hyperlink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) and `posixpath` etc. which can be used for path manipulation etc.

How would you improve this code? I'm open to using well-tested, popular libraries if that means less code and more stability.

Answer (score 2):

All in all, this is not bad. A few remarks:

## Python 2

Why choose Python 2? Python 3 has a lot of advantages, and will get more support in the future. Even if you need to code for Python 2, you can make your code compatible with both versions:

```
from __future__ import print_function
try:
    import urlparse
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import urllib.parse as urlparse
```

## docstring

Adding a docstring can better explain what the different methods do.

## `range`

You don't need the range as list, so you might as well use `xrange`.

To make the code Python 3 compatible, you'd have to add `xrange = range` to the except clause on the import, so this might not be worth it in this case, but in general, use the iterable version as much as possible.

## '/'

You do a lot of operations with `'/'`.

1. you remove a trailing `/` if it exists
2. you remove the starting `/` from `urlparse.urlparse(url).path` with `[1:]`
3. you add a trailing `/` in `get_domain_with_protocol` to the first part of the url

You can combine 1 and 2 by doing `path.strip('/')`. Or you can drop both 2 and 3, and iterate over `range(1, len(parts)`.

## generator

Instead of returning a list, you can also make a generator:

```
for index in range(len(parts)):
    yield domain_with_protocol + '/'.join(parts[:index + 1])
```

## iteration 1

In general I try not to do things like `range(len(parts))`, but use `enumerate`. Here you could do `for index, _ in enumerate(parts)`

## iteration 2

I try to avoid iterating over the index, and try to use generators as intermediate product instead of lists. Imagine `parts` would be an iterable instead of a list, your approach would not work. 
In Python 3, you could use `itertools.accumulate`, but in Python 2, you'd have to write your own accumulator:

```
def accumulate_parts(parts, sep='/'):
    parts_iter = iter(parts)
    substring = next(parts_iter)
    yield substring
    for part in parts_iter:
        substring += sep + part
        yield substring

def get_url_directories_accumulate(url):
    path = urlparse.urlparse(url).path
    parts = path.strip('/').split('/')
    domain_with_protocol = get_domain_with_protocol(url)
    for substring in accumulate_parts(parts):
        yield domain_with_protocol + substring
```

## timings

I've timed these variations both in Python 2 and Python 3, and all of them are within a few % of each other, so you can pick the one that suits you best, and you'll be able to understand in a few months/years.

## code

Full code and timings can be found [here](https://github.com/vadella/StackOverflow-questions/blob/master/url_dir_comb.ipynb).